# Event not attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function which dynamically creates an element and attaches a click event to this new element.

In the current state of my app, this function is called 5 times: for the 4 first created elements, all works fine, but the 5th one has no event attached!

I insist: I'm not merely saying that click doesn't work: Using `$._data(myElemn,'events')` in the console, I get `Object { click=[1]}` returned for the 4 working elements, but "undefined" for the last one.

Here is the code.
But I don't think is where the problem lies: since it works for other elements, It seems that the difference should come from the particular context of the 5th element.
So my question is rather: can we imagine which particular conditions may cause and event not to be attached (obviously,without any error message).

```
var createDDT= function(element) { /*
    ---------
Creates a drop-down toggle button embedded into element.
*/
  $(element).css({position:'relative'}) // (relative: since DDT pos is absolute)
  .append(
    $('<span \/>').addClass(DDT)
    .css({display:'none',})
    .append($('<span \/>'))
    // when click, toggle submenu:
    .click(function(event) {
      // hide or show current %Submenu:
      var submenu=$(event.target).closest('li').find(jqSUBMENU);
      submenu.toggleClass(OPEN);
      // hide any other %Open %Submenu:
      $(jqOPEN).not(submenu).removeClass(OPEN);
      setTimeout(liveWidthDisplay,_params.cssTimeout); // adjust LWD's position
      return false; // avoid following link, if embedded in <a>
    })
  );
}
```

[EDIT] As I previously said, the issue resides probably outside of the function. To emphasize it, in my app I tried replacing the code by the following:

```
var createDDT= function(element) { /*
    ---------
Creates a drop-down toggle button embedded into element.
*/
  $(element).css({position:'relative'}) // (relative: since DDT pos is absolute)
  .append(
    $('<span \/>').addClass(DDT)
    .css({display:'none',})
    .append($('<span \/>'))
    // when click, toggle submenu:
    .click(function(event) {
      alert(event.target.id);
    })
  );
}
```

Then the result is unchanged: `$._data(myElem,'events')` returns "undefined".

Unfortunately, I can't realistically add a significant context into jsFiddle, since it is a huge app.

Comment: can you edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZypNV/1/) to recreate the issue

Comment: it seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZypNV/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - your jsFiddle uses lots of undefined variables so it's kind of hard to show that full functionality is actually working.  The click handler in your jsFiddle, for example, doesn't do anything useful which is the OP's issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think OP is saying the click handler is not called.... in the fiddle it is throwing those reference errors so I was just trying to show OP that it is in fact getting called

Comment: @ArunPJohny - OK, your first comment could have been a lot clearer about what you meant by "working" then.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes... sorry about that.... should not have said it is working... :(

Comment: Careful, this line is a syntax error in Internet Explorer: `.css({display:'none',})`.

Comment: If you found the solution, add it as an answer. Don't edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can we imagine which particular conditions may cause and event not to
> be attached

Yes, either you aren't actually passing your 5th element to the `createDDT` function - or else you have some other code that is destroying the event handler - possibly innerHTML or some such.

In any case a better way to handle this, that will ensure you get the event is to attach a single event handler higher up in the DOM. For example on the `body`  (although any parent element that exists in the DOM will do).

```
// presuming DDT is a classname such as ".foo" 
$('body').on('click', DDT, function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});
```

This way you have a single event that you don't need to create for each element regardless of it is dynamically added to the DOM or not.

Comment: Despite the old age of my question (I must confess I can't remember now what is the app where I had to face to it!), I agree: your suggestion is clearly the best way to avoid a problem like mine.